# Azure App Service Mobile Apps - use custom data source instead of Table

Tags: cordova, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

We are planning to create a crossplatform mobile app, and I'm investigating some of technologies. Currently we are maiking choice between Xamarin and PhoneGap / Cordova. One of requirements is offline sync - the user must be able to work with app while there is no connection to server. When connection is restored, data must be synced.

I'm testing Azure App Service Mobile Apps for this purpose. But I'm faced with some strange thing. 
According to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk) Mobile Apps is designed to work with tables as data storage. It is required to create a single table, and to construct queries to that table on client. The client side SDK has methods like [getTable()](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/MobileServiceClient.html#getTable), which tells that SDK expexts to fetch data from table.

We have big legacy desktop app, which comes to each client with his own database. Client databases are hosted on VMs in data centers, which we rent. So we have some web service, which works directly with databases.

So here is the main question: can I somehow substitute table with calls to our web service in Mobile Apps backend? Is this technology designed for such usage? If not, can you suggest more suitable service, which can provide offline sync feature for mobile clients while pulling data from custom data sources?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I somehow substitute table with calls to our web service in Mobile Apps backend? Is this technology designed for such usage? If not, can you suggest more suitable service, which can provide offline sync feature for mobile clients while pulling data from custom data sources?

As far as I know, if you use aure C# mobile sdk backend, you could use mysql or something else which **support EF** as the database source. If you use azure Node.js backend, you could only use azure sql database and azure storage as the backend.

Since the azure mobile SDK provide the offline sync and other feature, it will create its own column to achieve the  offline sync.(About how azure mobile SDK achieve offline sync, you could refer to this [article](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/#the-version-field))

So if you use the SDK not supported database, you couldn't use the mobile SDK.
If you don't use azure mobile SDK, you will not use its feature.

If you still want to use other database(the SDK not supported), you need write your own logic to achieve all the feature you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the link on article and for clarification/